# How can I disable a kernel driver for a specific USB device? (re: driver is not compiled as a module)

Tags: linux, kernel, drivers, kernel-modules

Is it possible to prevent a kernel driver from loading for a specific USB device?

One approach is to use modprobe.conf and assign the USB device to a dummy module but this doesn't appear to work.  The Linux distribution I'm using is for an embedded system and has the driver I'm looking to disable compiled directly and NOT compiled as a module.

It looks like you can blacklist the initcall as a kernel boot parameter (initcall_blacklist=xx) but that also doesn't appear to work or I'm using the wrong method name.

I'm trying to black mt76x2u so I've tried:

init_blacklist=mt76x2_drv_init

Comment: Alternatively you can in user-mode, tell the system to ignore the device.

Comment: can you provide more information on that?  I need the USB device to be accessible by libusb (and not have the kernel driver attempt to communicate with it).

Comment: Sorry not my area of expertise. Just something I read about, and had to do one while following instructions. I don't know if it will be good enough. But maybe.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

`initcall_blacklist=mt76pci_probe,mt76x2u_probe`

Source: the Linux kernel source code.

initcall_blacklist **requires** CONFIG_KALLSYMS

Comment: I'll give that a try.  Thanks!  Is it normal that the mt76 driver code doesn't appear to have a module_init() or module_exit() methods?

Comment: I'm not sure how it all works. @StephenKit might have an answer. He originally offered a `init_blacklist` solution only nowadays it's called differently.