# Disable webcam at boot time, by appending a boot parameter

Tags: linux-kernel, boot, camera, kernel-parameters

I have an internal webcam on my Dell laptop. I don't see it listed with [`lspci`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lspci), but it works.

I am using a self-compiled kernel, and here are the options I have enabled:

```
# zcat /proc/config.gz | grep -v '^#' | egrep '(MEDIA|VIDEO)'
CONFIG_ACPI_VIDEO=y
CONFIG_MEDIA_SUPPORT=y
CONFIG_MEDIA_SUPPORT_FILTER=y
CONFIG_MEDIA_CAMERA_SUPPORT=y
CONFIG_VIDEO_DEV=y
CONFIG_MEDIA_CONTROLLER=y
CONFIG_VIDEO_V4L2=y
CONFIG_VIDEO_V4L2_I2C=y
CONFIG_MEDIA_USB_SUPPORT=y
CONFIG_USB_VIDEO_CLASS=y
CONFIG_VIDEOBUF2_CORE=y
CONFIG_VIDEOBUF2_V4L2=y
CONFIG_VIDEOBUF2_MEMOPS=y
CONFIG_VIDEOBUF2_VMALLOC=y
CONFIG_SND_USB_AUDIO_USE_MEDIA_CONTROLLER=y
```

All options in my kernel are compiled statically, and I am not using loadable modules.

How can I disable the webcam at boot time, by passing/appending something to the kernel boot options?

I would like to decide at boot time whether I want to boot the kernel with webcam support, or without.

Comment: A webcam is unlikely to be a PCI device. Look for it in lsusb.

Comment: I don't see how this can be done with a kernel parameter, because with a statically linked kernel, you can't blacklist a module. Uh a kernel without module loading is usually security-wise a bad idea, as you need to include all functionality that you might *eventually* use *always* in the kernel. It's also hard to use. You're using a shared-library based userland with more than a single init executable. What was the consideration that made building a non-module-loading kernel the right choice?

Comment: @Marcus Müller - I am already using kernel boot parameters to disable some other kernel components. For example my audio card: `snd-hda-intel.enable=0,1`. This works fine, and I don't see why same could not work for webcam.

Comment: But it doesn't work. That `enable` switch is specific to the `snd-hda-intel` module, and doesn't exist for e.g. `uvcvideo` (which is most likely the driver for your webcam). Again, the fact that you're having a static kernel with everything included makes it hard to disable parts of it. You'd essentially have to choose between different kernels, instead of choosing kernel parameters, at boottime.

Comment: So: *What was the consideration that made building a non-module-loading kernel the right choice?* This greatly influences which kind of directions you can take from here, that's why I'm asking. You have had some consideration why you're doing this, which is central to the problem at hand, so doing the "right" thing depends on knowing the original purpose. If a solution defeats that purpose, it's not a solution for you at all, and writing it would waste everyone's time.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I disable a kernel driver for a specific USB device? (re: driver is not compiled as a module)](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/615332/how-can-i-disable-a-kernel-driver-for-a-specific-usb-device-re-driver-is-not) Or [this one](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/276392/106927)?

Comment: Can you please provide some more information about your webcam? Do you already know which driver your webcam is using? Why do you think lspci should list your webcam? Is your webcam a PCI device? And also @MarcusMuller mentioned look for it in "lsusb", I am not really sure about this as well, This is an internal webcam and not really a USB gadget. So, Providing more information about your webcam might help to answer better.

Comment: @Thushi internal webcams are typically connected via USB too.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

If `CONFIG_KALLSYMS` is enabled, built-in drivers can be disabled by [disabling their `init` function](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/468038/86440). For `uvcvideo` (which is likely to be the driver used for your webcam), add

```
initcall_blacklist=uvc_video_init
```

to your kernel’s command line.

If it isn’t, you won’t be able to disable *only* your webcam using kernel command line parameters, but you can control your webcam at run-time; find its entry in `/sys/bus/usb/devices`, and write 0 to the corresponding `authorized` file, *e.g.*

```
echo 0 | sudo tee /sys/bus/usb/devices/1-8/authorized
```

Write 1 to enable the camera again.

You can use [USBGuard](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/412011/86440) to provide control over all your USB devices, including your webcam.

Comment: thank you, but appending `initcall_blacklist=uvc_video_init` to my boot parameters has no effect. The device `/dev/video0` still exists, and the webcam still works.

Comment: Does your camera use the `uvcvideo` driver?

Comment: how can I find out? My laptops are Dell Latitude E6540 and Dell Latitude E7440. I believe they are using standard webcams over USB interface.

Comment: based on answer from a related question, `initcall_blacklist` needs `CONFIG_KALLSYMS` to work. But I don't have KALLSYMS in my kernel:  https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/615332/how-can-i-disable-a-kernel-driver-for-a-specific-usb-device-re-driver-is-not

Comment: Ah, you should have seen a warning in your boot logs (“initcall_blacklist requires CONFIG_KALLSYMS”).

Answer (score 1):

Not meant as an answer to the problem. Only explaining why "*You just cannot!*" is the only possible answer to the question as worded in the title :

---

It is indeed possible to pass boot parameters of the kind :

```
module_name.parameter_name=parameter_value
```

Which will be honored by some in-kernel built module_name driver at the condition the driver accepts the parameter_name and parameter_value is within the range of accepted values.

The usb-storage driver would for example be able to ignore one particular usb storage device using a boot command line parameter of the kind :

```
usb-storage.quirks=03f0:b002:iu
```

Because the usb-storage is programmed in order to honor the quirks parameter and decode its value as representing Vendor-Id:Product-Id and i meaning IGNORE_DEVICE.

If the uvcvideo driver does honor a *[quirks](https://www.ideasonboard.org/uvc/faq/)* parameter, it unfortunately, offers no particular value for that parameter aiming at ignoring any device.